# Calling receiver from pendingIntent in notifications

Tags: android

So I changed my code to call a broadcast receiver instead of calling the main activity

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, com.plugin.statusNotificationForGCM.statusNotificationForGCMReceiver.class);

notificationIntent.putExtra(NOTIF_RESPOND, runThis);
notificationIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
notificationIntent = notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);

//contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
contentIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

The problem is I added this in my receiver, but don't think its running. Don't see the tag and  Log in the console when I click the notification

```
public class statusNotificationForGCMReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "statusNOTIFICATIONReceiver";

    @Override
    public final void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.v(TAG,"ASDFSJD FASDF ASDPFJA SDFPAUS DFPAS DFASDF");
    }
}
```

Is there something I am missing?  Do I have to add something to the manifest file?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may need to have this in manifest :

Suitable intents are defined in its `<intent-filter>`

```
<activity android:name="BroadcastIntents" android:label="@string/app_name"/>
    <receiver android:name="statusNotificationForGCMReceiver" android:label="@string/app_name">
       <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.test.BROADCAST" />
       </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Addenda:

an [intent filter](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html) lets you tell an activity what it can/cannot respond to (when called by intent).

```
public class InternalMessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
        String msg = intent.getStringExtra("message");
        Toast.makeText(ctx,msg,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

You can call it in an Activity for instance for a button clicked like this:

```
private static final String ACTION = "android.test.BROADCAST";

public void onClick(View v) {
        /* Broadcast intent */
        Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION);
        intent.putExtra("message", msg);
        main_activity.sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

Comment: Hi Ali,
This worked.
Thanks. 
However, I wanted to ask you. I have the receiver name and intent filter "android:name" attributes as the same.  Can you provide an example as to when they should be different?  Trying to get the big picture. 
Thanks

Comment: I edited my answer, check the link and read more about intent filter.